# How to apply cluster analysis to a database in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I have a base that shows me the answers of the applicants to a course. The original base is 2k rows and 105 columns, of which 100 correspond to questions from 4 basic areas of mathematics, language, science, and social.
I have created the following short example so that you can see more or less how the table is

```
sector<-c("Privado" ,"Publico" ,"Publico" ,"Publico", "Publico", 
"Publico" ,"Publico", "Publico", "Publico" ,"Publico", "Publico",
"Publico" ,"Publico", "Publico", "Publico" ,"Privado" ,"Publico" ,
"Publico" ,"Publico" ,"Publico")

aspirante<-c("337877" ,"339161", "388425" ,"371828" ,"288598" ,"396295" ,"400196",
 "370915", "276891" ,"335406" ,"358013", "404406", "356633", "284792", "372549" ,
"271082", "396135" ,"398664" ,"406397", "354609")

claves<-c("10" ,"9" , "10", "4" , "4" , "3" , "3" , "4" , "9"  ,"10", "3",  
"3" , "3" , "4" , "4" , "4" , "4",  "4"  ,"9" , "3")

question1<-c(1, 0, 0, 0 ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0 ,0, 0, 0 ,0, 0, 0 ,0, 0, 0 ,1, 0)

question2<-c(0, 1, 1 ,0 ,0, 0 ,0 ,0 ,1, 0, 0,0,1 ,0 ,1, 1, 0 ,0, 0, 0)

question3<-c( 0 ,0, 1, 1, 1 ,1 ,0, 0, 0 ,0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

question4<-c(0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)

question5<-c(1, 0, 1, 0 ,0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0 ,0 ,0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0)

note<-c(4 ,2, 6, 4, 2, 6, 0 ,4, 4 ,0, 4 ,4 ,6, 2, 4 ,4, 4, 2, 4, 2)

example<-data.frame("candidate"=aspirante,"sector"=sector,"p1"=question1,
"p2"=question2,"p3"=question3,"p4"=question4,"p5"=question5,"note"=note)
```

[image]

the note column is equal to the sum of the row multiplied by 2

I am asked to do a cluster analysis but I have no idea what to do, I had planned to divide the final notes into 4 categories:

failed: grades less than 3

considered: between 3 and 5

space availability: between 5 and 7

approved: from 7 to 10

but in the original base the sizes of each will vary and I cannot create a new base that divides the notes by group. Do you have any suggestions or an example where cluster analysis is applied to dichotomous data?

Comment: Cluster analysis is rather vague. Perhaps have a read at [examples of k-means clustering](https://www.datanovia.com/en/lessons/k-means-clustering-in-r-algorith-and-practical-examples/) and see if it fit your needs.

Comment: What is "notes"? Your description suggests you just want to divide the data into groups based on that column? Also you define "claves" but it is not included in your data frame. What is it? Is "grade" just the sum of the values in each row?

Comment: right now i fix that each question is worth 2 points